# Paperclip not displaying any error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Paperclip not displaying the error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796703/paperclip-not-displaying-the-error-message)

I am using rails 3.2.6. I have added this in my models file:

```
has_one :avatar, :as => :imageable, :dependent => :destroy
 validates_presence_of :avatar, :message => "can't be empty"
```

But I am not getting any error message if the field is left blank.I am only getting `Please review the problems below:` at the top of my page. Can anyone suggest anything?

I also tried:

```
validates :avatar, :presence => {:message => 'Please select the image'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The :avatar field is not a real field. Do the check on avatar_id, which is the real database field:

```
validates :avatar_id, :presence => true
```

see: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html section 3.9 examples.

Comment: Actually it is accepts_nested_attributes:  has_one :avatar, :as => :imageable, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :attachments, :as => :attachable, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :avatar

Comment: I do :reject_if => :all_blank and it does not allow me to go further but the error message is not displayed.

Comment: Are other field errrors displayed? Maybe your code to display the errors is the problem?

Comment: The field for avatar is taken like this:  <%= f.simple_fields_for :avatar do |image_form| %>
      <%= image_form.input :avatar, :as => :file  %>

  <% end %>  .Other fields are displaying the error message properly.

Comment: Have you actually tried my suggestion?